# More pythonic way of filtering out stable values in a list

Tags: python, list, functional-programming, filtering, purely-functional

I wrote a function that allows me to run through a list, compare the values with the predecessors, and assert at which point the list becomes "stable" for a certain amount of entries.
The values in the list represent a signal, that may or not reach a stable point.
I came up with this:

```
def unstableFor(points, maxStable):
    count = 0;
    prev = points[0]
    for i in range(1, len(points)):
        if points[i] == prev:
            count = count + 1
        else:
            count = 0
            prev = points[i]
        if count >= maxStable:
            return i
    return len(points) - 1
```

The returned value is then used by the caller for cutting away the last part of the list.

It does its job, however, I am quite dissatisfied with how cumbersome it looks. Can you think of a more pythonic, possibly purely-functional way of performing this filtering operation?

Comment: On a side note, I think `count` should start from 1

Comment: You could also show a sample input list and the expected output

Comment: Must the entries be always successive to qualify as stable?

Comment: Yes, they must be subsequent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use enumerating and zipping:

```
def unstableFor (points, threshold):
    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(points, points[1:])):
        count = count + 1 if a == b else 0
        if count >= threshold:
            return i
    return i
```

Comment: `zip(points, points[1:])` is more economic in terms of memory usage than `zip(points[:-1], points[1:])` and they both yield the same result in Python 2 and 3 respectively.

Comment: I believe this is a very good mix of imperative and functional: it's clear and very compact. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch for a functional approach. It's a bit cryptic. Indeed, I would likely use your approach (using `enumerate` as is the idiomatic way instead of `range(len(x))`). Anyway, supposing `max_stable` is 3:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> grouped = groupby(enumerate(x), lambda i_e: i_e[1])
>>> gen = (g for g in map(lambda e: list(e[1]), grouped) if len(g) >= 3)
>>> run = next(gen)
>>> run[2][0]
10
```

Here it is cleaned up:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> def unstable_for(points, max_stable):
...     grouped = groupby(enumerate(points), itemgetter(1))
...     gen = (g for g in (tuple(gg) for _, gg in grouped) if len(g) >= max_stable)
...     run = tuple(islice(gen,1))
...     if len(run) == 0:
...         return len(points) - 1
...     else:
...         return run[0][max_stable - 1][0]
...
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9]
>>> unstable_for(x, 3)
10
>>> unstable_for(x, 2)
3
>>> unstable_for(x, 1)
0
>>> unstable_for(x, 20)
13
>>>
```

Not very elegant. Again, I would go with the imperative solution. Maybe someone has a more elegant functional solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine to me: it is easy to read and to understand. I would just remove some repetitions to make it look like:

```
def unstableFor(points, maxStable):
    prev = None  # assuming None is not member of points
    for i, point in enumerate(points):
        if point == prev:
            count = count + 1
        else:
            count = 0
            prev = point
        if count >= maxStable:
            break
    return i
```

Comment: I would say this is the most *Pythonic* way.